# Error : No such file or directory: 'satu.txt'

Tags: python

I want to read multiple text files in the folder. I am using os.listdir() to get every file in my folder. I'm using open to read the text file and write to write the file. However, an error comes out when I run the code. 
Here I attached the code.

```
import os
infilename = os.listdir("C:\Python27\input") 
for filename in infilename:
    f = open(filename, "r")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
```

Comment: Where do you put your script and how do you run it? You might have the wrong relative path

Comment: I put the script inside of Python folder. I run using Python Shell. When I print filename, It shows the name of my files but can't read it. like this,

Comment: for filename in infilename:
 print filename 
satu.txt
satu2.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` will return just the filenames, you need to combine the file name, with the directory name in order for `open` to find it:

```
import os

infilename = os.listdir(r'C:\Python27\input')
for filename in infilename:
    f = open(os.path.join(r'C:\Python27\input', filename), 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
```

If you are using `\` in a string, you should use raw strings, so characters such as `\n` are taken literally and not interpreted; the `r'` at the beginning of the string marks it  as a raw string (so Python takes it literally).

Comment: I already can read and write all files inside the folder using this code.May I know, why the result saves only one file. It replaces an old one with a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your python script is in the same directory, you will get this error.

You need to reference the full path to the file, not just the file name.

```
import os

indir = "C:\Python27\input"

for filename in os.listdir(indir):
    fullpath = os.path.join(indir,filename)
    with open(fullpath, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `os.listdir` only returns the files in that directory, only the names. You must add the path in front of the file name for it to work.

```
import os
import sys

drive = os.path.splitdrive(sys.executable)[0]
drive = os.path.join(drive, "Python27")
drive = os.path.join(drive, "input")
infilename = os.listdir(drive)
for filename in infilename:
    f = open(os.path.join(drive, filename), "r")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
```

Comment: Always use `os.path.join` instead of `+` when building file paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = "C:\\Python27\\input"
infilename = os.listdir(path) 
for filename in infilename:
    print(path + "\\"+ filename)
    f = open(path + "\\" + filename, "r")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
```